# How to prevent cherry-pick from automerging?

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to do a cherry-pick to some commit.
The current version of my file has the following content:
`functionDeterminer.setupEval({}, {});`

After the cherry-pick it's automerged with
`functionDeterminer.setupEval({});`

Why is it automerged? Isn't it supposed to make a conflict? So how can I prevent that?

I've tried `git cherry-pick --no-commit <commit-hash>`, but still automerging happens. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: a conflict showing up in a cherry-pick depends on what the file looks (at that section) like in `HEAD`, what it looks like in the commit you are cherry-picking **and its parent**. Without those 3 pieces of information, we can't really tell if a conflict should be raised or not. And **welcome to SO!**

Comment: @eftshift0 The content of the two files are the same but this line only changes.

Comment: we need not 2 but _3_ pieces of information and we need to know what each one looks like _exactly_ at that point.

Comment: It looks like this is a non-conflicting change. The source commit of the cherry-pick introduced that new version of the line, I guess? You'd have to give us a bit more details if you want more useful answers. For instance, can you show us the state of that line in the commit you cherry-picked? *(My money is on* `functionDeterminer.setupEval({});`)